# Locking a thread depending on other thread's current programming counter

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Here is a generalized code I am working on. The problem is how to halt 2nd_thread till all sub_threads have been executed and main_thread is sleeping. Similarly the main_thread too will wait on returning back for while loop execution. The main_thread would wait till 2nd_thread has executed if it is currently executing.

I thought of using global variable which can be modified by threads to inform 2nd_thread whether it should start executing or not. However, the global variable may be accessed at the same time by multiple threads causing issues.

I even thought of locking sub_threads, main_thread and 2nd_thread with a static object but if I lock sub_threads then there is no multithreading of sub_threads anymore.

How to solve this?

```
void main()  
{    
    //Do something here  

    Thread thread1 = new thread(main_thread);  
    thread1.start();  

    //Do something here  

    if(something) //Button event  
    {
         Thread thread2 = new Thread(2nd_thread)  
         thread2.start();
    } 
}  

void main_thread()
{
    while(true)
    {  
        //Do something  
        if(after something, if condition true)
        {
            new Thread(sub_thread).start();  
        }
        //Do something
        Thread.sleep(_sometime_);
    }  

}  

void 2nd_thread()  
{
    //This thread must execute only if main_thread is sleeping   
    //and all sub_threads have been executed. Till then wait for  
    //other threads to execute.  
}

void sub_thread()  
{  
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: Are you sure threads are the right tool for this job? Might there be a more natural way to express this using `Task`s instead?

Comment: What with the "while(true)" and all, it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do here. That said, my first question is, if the "2nd_thread" code is only supposed to execute once "main_thread" is sleeping (why is it sleeping?) and the "sub_thread" threads are all done, why not just have "main_thread" wait on the "sub_thread" threads and then execute the work that you are currently doing in "2nd_thread"? Why does that "2nd_thread" exist at all, if it's only going to execute when you've already got a thread sitting there idle?

Comment: @PeterDuniho Sorry, I corrected the code have a look now. The 2nd_thread would be called on button event and is a thread as I don't want the main GUI thread to get stuck.

Comment: Are you even sure you need to use Multithreading. Is your process CPU bound?

Comment: Sorry...even with the edits, I find the example too vague. It's still not clear why the main_thread is sleeping, not clear where and how it's waiting on the sub_threads, and not clear what the relationship is between main_thread and 2nd_thread. You got an answer mentioning CountDownEvent, and I agree that _might_ address your need. But without a better code example, I'm loathe to speculate.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Both 2nd_thread and main_thread utilizes serial port for transmission. I don't want both threads to be transmitting at the same time. main_thread would be continuously looking for a condition to transmit data, so to give 2nd_thread a chance to transmit data I have sleep in the main_thread.

Sub_threads are used for receiving data from serial port. So the 2nd_thread needs to wait till serial port is free. This would only be possible if all sub_threads have completed their execution and main_thread is asleep.

Comment: @Aron Yes I need multithreading as I am continuously looking for a condition to transfer data to serial port in the main_thread and need multithreading of sub_threads as I am waiting for particular data to be received which if not received in given time.

Comment: @shyamalparikh That is exactly what I am talking about. That is NOT a case you should use Threading for (at least in .net). You are I/O (latency) bound not CPU bound. Please read [Stephen Cleary's There is no Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). Threading will cause more issues than it will solve. Stick to single threaded asynchronous code.

Comment: @shyamalparikh: I'll be contrarian here to a degree and say that multithreaded code is not always about solving CPU bound problems. It's fine to have threads for other reasons. That said, it seems to me that since what you are really dealing with there is a resource contention issue, not a threading issue, that you ought to simply use a lock to synchronize access to the serial port resource. Then any thread can try to issue serial I/O, but only one at a time can. IMHO this is best done by abstracting the whole serial I/O into its own class which handles the synchronization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without venturing into other threading frameworks, you can probably achieve what you want with a [CountDownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent%28VS.100%29.aspx) (There are actually a lot of details missing in your question but that can give you a good start).

Declare a shared CountDownEvent. 
Assuming the number of worker threads spawned by main_thread is knwon in advance, you can initialize the event with this number. The last line of code in the workers would be to decrement (=`Signal()`) the counter .

The first line of code of the 2nd_thread would be to `Wait()` on the event. Thus, only when its internal count hits zero (i.e. all the worker threads are finished) it will resume execution.

If you do not know the number of workers in advance, each new worker can increment the counter dynamically, but than you need to handle all kinds of race conditions (like 2nd thread starting to work before the very first worker had the chance to increment the counter..).

Comment: I think this would work. However, I failed to mention that main thread too have to wait on returning back to execute while loop code. It would have to wait till all sub_threads and 2nd_threads are done executing if currently executing. (Updated my Question too.)

Comment: This is a simple critical section, just use lock(someSharedObject) for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot I tried CountDownEvent and its working perfectly. Just that I cannot allow it to go down till 0 or it throws an exception when a count is added again. It's currentcount property does the trick though.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx), a thread synchronization primitive which is very useful in these situations. If you *knew the number of sub threads upfront*, you could create a list of these wait handles and wait all on them, including the main thread. The second thread could then signal the main thread once that has finished processing. Admittedly not the prettiest, but I've tried an example, e.g.:

```
private AutoResetEvent _mainThreadWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private AutoResetEvent _secondThreadWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
private List<AutoResetEvent> _subThreadWaitHandles = new List<AutoResetEvent>();

void main()  
{    
    //Do something here

    for(int i = 0; i < numSubThreads; i++) // TODO: Need to know numSubThreads.
      _subThreadWaitHandles.Add(new AutoResetEvent(false));

    Thread thread1 = new thread(main_thread);  
    thread1.start();  

    //Do something here  

    if(something) //Button event  
    {
         Thread thread2 = new Thread(2nd_thread)  
         thread2.start();
    } 
}  

void main_thread()
{
    while(true)
    {  
        //Do something  
        if(after something, if condition true)
        {
           // TODO: Need to work out which sub thread you are on if you know the number of thee sub threads up front and assign resetIndex with
           // that particular indexed sub thread...
           int setIndex = i; // TODO: work out i.
            new Thread(() => sub_thread(setIndex)).start();  
        }
        //Do something

        // signal second thread it can proceed - however second thread is probably still waiting on all sub threads....
        _mainThreadWaitHandle.Set();
        Thread.sleep(_sometime_);

        // now wait for second thread to complete...
        _secondThreadWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }  

}  

void 2nd_thread()  
{
    //This thread must execute only if main_thread is sleeping   
    //and all sub_threads have been executed. Till then wait for  
    //other threads to execute.

    List<WaitHandle> allWaitHandles = new List<WaitHandle>(_subThreadWaitHandles);
    allWaitHandles.Add(_mainThreadWaitHandle);

    // Wait on all sub threads and the main thread.
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(allWaitHandles.ToArray()); 

    // do stuff

    //now signal to inform main thread it can proceed.
    _secondThreadWaitHandle.Set();
}

void sub_thread(int setIndex)  
{  
     //Do something

     //Now signal to inform this has completed.
     _subThreadWaitHandles[setIndex].Set();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, the number of sub_threads cannot be known upfront. I think CountDownEvent is a better option, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, a CountDownEvent may be better suited. I will try update my answer with an example using that if I get more time :)

Answer (score 1):

Your actual issue is that you need asynchronous code and not concurrent code. What you have managed to write is synchronous-concurrent code.

Your "Main Thread" is actually a UI Thread. You should NEVER EVER EVER EVER call anything that can block on your UI thread. `Thread.Sleep` is guaranteed to block for at least x milliseconds.

What you actually WANTED to do was spin up a new thread, then when it completed, invoke some update on the main thread. Asynchronous-Concurrent code.

You would typically do this by using `Control.Invoke(delegate)` on your WinForm or use `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(delegate)`. Its a pain to do and not very efficient, but it was the only way we knew how to do it back in the 2000s (the poor gits in JAVA still do it).

Its now 2014. You want to use Asynchronous-SingleThreaded code. Here you wrap up your Serial Port access with a `Task` and internally you have an event that threadlessly signals your serial port has data for you. You then use the WinForm message pump to schedule work to deal with the Serial Port and interleave the work with updating your UI, using a single thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I need to look at Task coding, not familiar with it.

Just to clarify the main_thread is not actually the UI thread. I made it especially because I didn't want it to block UI thread. Btw I am using control.invoke(delegate) currently. 

I would also like to know the solution to the problem of threading in my question.

Comment: You could just create a static object then call `lock(object)` on it.

Comment: In the question I clearly mentioned that I cannot have `lock(object)` as then the sub_threads would become singlethread.